# Is there a word or phrase, nominal or adjectival, for someone who wants to know everything about everything?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

With Youtube, I find myself learning about everything – in depth!  Is there a word for someone who is a visual learner, who desires to learn everything about anything and everything?  I am not a scholar and the answer does not necessarily have to require "book" learning.

I just really enjoy learning about things that interest me, including the history of such things (as in knitting), the methodology of things (fishing, cooking, boating, gardening, etc etc!)

Is there such a word or phrase?

Comment: [Faust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzMejWGirJs).

Answer (score 3):

***Insatiably curious*** might better fit the extent of the curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

Try **pantomath**

> - *A pantomath is a person who wants to know everything.*

[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantomath)]

Also interesting is the fact that he wants to achieve [pansophy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pansophy) or [omniscience](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Omniscience).

Comment: This is unintentionally deceptive. The Wikipedia article is still under consideration for deletion. There are no recorded uses of this word. It appears that someone has used Wikipedia in order to introduce a neologism.

Answer (score 0):

**Curious person**

eager to learn or know

**Inquisitive person**

given to inquiry, research, or asking questions; eager for knowledge; intellectually curious

Answer (score 0):

what about pansophic, from pansophy? (*pan-*: all-inclusive, especially in relation to the whole of a continent, racial group, religion, etc. *-sophy*: knowledge, wisdom etc.)

Comment: It exists as a word, Antonio, and might be  a candidate here, but I'd say its default sense is in a different domain from the spot on 'insatiably curious'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are are many fancy words you'll come across, however, I prefer *wonderer* or *learner*.

Answer (score 0):

**Sponge**.

He's like a sponge, absorbing knowledge of books and just by watching people workin'.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/soak-up) gives:

soak up something | INTERMEDIATE ENGLISH
soak up something
phrasal verb with soak verb
US  /soʊk/

to absorb or enjoy something that exists around you:

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a word for someone who is a visual learner, who desires to learn everything about anything and everything?

No. There is not.

English does not have a "word of everything". After seven years, we can safely say that there is no such word in English.

The answers given so far seem to concentrate on a person who possesses knowledge in a particular field rather than someone - a student - who is pursuing all knowledge in an indiscriminate manner.

Further, the criterion of "visual learner" makes it less likely that there would be such a word.

Comment: Why does 'pantomath' not fulfil this requirement? There are a substantial number of hits, many relevant, in a Google search, and Wikipedia licenses it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *Wikipedia licenses it* - the article states: **"The word itself is not to be found in common online English dictionaries, the OED, dictionaries of obscure words, or dictionaries of neologisms.[1]"** The entry bears the hallmarks of  an attempt to give credence to the author's word. As further evidence, we have **"A pantomath is a person who (i) wants to know or (ii) knows everything."**  One word for such contrasting definitions would be remarkable - I can think of no other word that has such conflict.

Comment: _Pantomath_ is **typically** used to convey the sense that a great individual has achieved a pinnacle of learning, .... Appearance in Wikipedia is itself a measure of acceptance.  // A _suspicious_ person is one who typically suspects others or one who merits suspicion from others. Took seconds. There are many words with conflicting definitions. // You've also missed half the question, as reasonably broadened.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I note that you have not addressed the problem with the Wiki entry: if you are using it as evidence, you might wish to do that.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ***Took seconds.*** and bears no relation to the alleged contrasting meanings of "pantomath"...