# Word for someone who wants to know all (not pantomath)

Tags: single-word-requests

This question has already been asked somewhat, "[Word for someone who wants to know everything about everything](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324421/word-for-someone-who-wants-to-know-everything-about-everything)" The best definition given was pantomath, the problem with pantomath is that it means someone who knows all (along with wants to know all), while I'm looking for a word that describes someone who *wants to know all* or wants to become omniscient, a pantomath, etc.

John is a(n) (insert word) he's always telling me he wants to learn everything he can.

Comment: You really want a single word? The answer to the linked question *insatiably curious* sounds perfect otherwise.

Comment: I agree with your distrust of "pantomath", which seems to be an invention, as it is not found as a word in any English texts.

Comment: OP doesn't want 'pantomath' on the grounds of polysemy, not non-wordness, Greybeard. / I've CV-ed as the other question encompassed this one. A subset of answers there should echo any here.

Answer (score 1):

John is **insatiable**. He's always telling me he wants to learn everything he can.

> Impossible to satiate or satisfy: an [insatiable](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/insatiable) appetite; an
>   **insatiable hunger for knowledge**.

Answer (score 0):

philomath
[Someone who loves to learn](https://knowledgelover.com/word-for-someone-who-loves-to-learn/)

Comment: We would prefer that you quote a definition from a recognized dictionary (and also link to that definition), rather than just linking to a site that quotes from a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Polymath is someone who learns many subjects.

Panmath may work as one who learns all. Or more simply, knowall.

But "wants" are lacks, so perhaps panphilosopher.

> Through desire a man, having separated himself, seeketh and intermeddleth with all wisdom. – Proverb